# then there exist $m,n$ such $(m!)\cdot (n!)\equiv r\pmod p$

Tags: number-theory

let $p$is give odd prime number,show that: for any postive integer $r$,then there exists postive ineteger $m,n$ such that
$$(m!)\cdot (n!)\equiv r\pmod p$$

I try use this $$(m)!\equiv (p+1)(p+2)\cdots (p+m) \pmod p$$
$$(n)!\equiv (p+1)(p+2)\cdots (p+n) \pmod p$$
so
$$(m!)\cdot (n!)\equiv (p+1)(p+2)\cdots (p+m) (p+1)(p+2)\cdots (p+n)\pmod p$$
But I can't it

Comment: According to Conjecture 1 of http://emis.impa.br/EMIS/journals/INTEGERS/papers/g21/g21.pdf, it seems that this is an unproved conjecture for $(r,p) \ne (7,11)$.

Comment: Because $m,n < p$, we can exhaustively check for small $p$. The only counterexample I found for primes up to 500 is indeed $p=11$, for which $r=7$ is not possible. This sole exception also means a simple algebraic proof is unlikely to be successful.